# Where do you put modified WSDL files for the API to override the core definitions?

Tags: api, overrides, ee-1.12, wsdl

We've updated the standard WSDL definitions to support bundled product attributes for sku_type and price_type.  I've tried putting the updated WSDL and WSI files in `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/etc/`, but Magento doesn't load them. I don't want to leave them in the core area, but that seems to be the only place I can get Magento to find them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have wsdl definitions in the local folder also.
What you need to do is to create a custom module. In your custom module you can add the files `api.xml`, `wsdl.xml` and `wsi.xml` inside the `etc` folder.

Your `wsdl.xml` file should be taken into consideration when building the actual wsdl. Magento merges all `wsdl.xml` files from all the modules that have one (same goes for `api.xml` and `wsi.xml`). These files are merged, so you don't need the full xml file from `Mage_Catalog` model. You can add only the pieces you need, just make sure you keep the same path.

Here is a simple example. In `wsdl.xml` from `Mage_Catalog` there is this piece of code:

```
<definitions...>
    <types>
        <schema ...>
            <complexType name="catalogProductEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="product_id" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="sku" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="set" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="category_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
                    <element name="website_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

And you want to add an other field to this type, all you have to do in your wsdl.xml file from your custom module is this:

```
    <definitions...>
        <types>
            <schema ...>
                <complexType name="catalogProductEntity">
                    <all>
                        <element name="custom_attribute" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </all>
                </complexType>
            </schema>
        </types>
    </definitions>
```

(add the attributes for the tags definitions and schema that I've replaced with '...').

Comment: Thanks Marius, that makes sense. I'll add these definitions to our custom module and have it add to the master WSDL definition.  I wasn't thinking of these as similar to layout and config files.  Magic!

Comment: This is really handy.

Comment: Marius, I want to overwrite the catalogProductAttributeSetAttributeAdd response from bool to int. But now it's showing both. How do I do that?