# Howto read/update newly created custom category attribute via SOAP API V2 - ASP.NET/C#

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, api

I managed to create a custom attribute for a category using custom module and following 'sqlscript':

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label'=> 'Legacy Id',
    'input' => 'text',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'legacy_id', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Attribute is visible and editable in admin section.

Now I want to read/update this attribute through SOAP API V2 in a asp.net/c# application, but I am not able to get to the custom attribute.
When I use `catalogCategoryAttributeList` I get a list of all attributes including the one I created, however when I use method `catalogCategoryInfo` it shows only default attributes. I am not sure what parameter `string[] attribute` does. No matter what I put here, I always get the same result.
And I assume that I need to use that method to get to the attributes of that category ([according to magento API documentation on getting category info](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.info.html)).

Code-snippet:

```
catalogAttributeEntity[] List = Service.catalogCategoryAttributeList(SessionKey);
catalogAttributeEntity LegacyIdAttr = List.Where(c => c.code == "legacy_id").FirstOrDefault();
Category = Service.catalogCategoryInfo(SessionKey, 5681, null, null);
```

I hope someone can put me in the right direction on how to get my custom attribute and
possibly change it's value.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seams that the API for categories does not work similar to the products. For the products you can get and set 'additional_attributes'.
In my opinion you need to extend the type definitions for the category methods to make your field behave just like the core fields.
[Here are some details about how you can extend the type definitions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1331/)
The explanations are for extending types related to the products, but you can do the same for categories.
The main idea is to create an extension, add the file `etc/wsdl.xml` inside the extension (and wsi.xml if you use WSI Complience). In `wsdl.xml` add your missing attributes, and Magento will merge your file with the ones from the core.
You need to extend the following types `catalogCategoryInfo`, `catalogCategoryEntityCreate`

Comment: Thank you @Marius, this did the job for added the attribute. I can see the created attribute through the api using c#, but I think I missed something else because the value is allways null. I can update the attribute in Magento admin, value gets saved into the database. Do you have ideas how to get/update the newly created attribute through the api?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Maybe it doesn't pass this validation: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Api_Resource::_isAllowedAttribute`  called from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api_V2::info()`.