# Get correct product URL from SOAP API

Tags: product, api, url, multistore, soap

Using the SOAP API, how can I get URL for the product (when requesting from `catalog_product.info`) that will **always** work?

Using `url_key` and appending `".html"` is not good enough because in many stores that won't work.

So at the moment I have this:

```
$url = $shop_url . '/catalog/product/view/id/' . $product_id;
```

The `$shop_url` being the domain eg `http://www.store.com`.

The only issue with that is that the product may not be visible on all stores.... E.g. a single magento may have more than one storefront, each with a different url and each showing a subset of products... so thats hard.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I will also accept an answer which would give me a way to test, positively, that the ID method above would work for different stores.

Comment: What kind of problems are you seeing from using the url_key from the catalog_product.info API calls that are not "always" working? What isn't working across the multiple stores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but here is a simple extension that allows you to get the product url.
The main idea is to rewrite the `info` method in the product api model and make it return the url of the product also.
For this you will need the following files:
**`app/etc/modules/[Namespace]_[Module].xml`** - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
                <Mage_Api />
            </depends>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**`app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/config.xml`** - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_api>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Product_Api</product_api>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**`app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Product/Api.php`** - your new class

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Product_Api extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api {
    public function info($productId, $store = null, $attributes = null, $identifierType = null){
        $product = $this->_getProduct($productId, $store, $identifierType);
        $result = parent::info($productId, $store = null, $attributes = null, $identifierType = null);
        //add a new element in here called product_url. You can even wrap it in some condition to see if the product is assigned to the current website or if the product is enabled or visible. ($product->getWebsiteIds(), $product->getStatus(), $product->getVisibility()). 
        $result['product_url'] = $product->getUrlInStore($store);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Note: This works only for API V1. In order to make it work for v2 you need to add a wsdl to your module. [See how you can do it](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1331/146).

Answer (score 1):

I think url_path is a more accurate choice than url_key. I'm not certain but I think url_path ends up being a unique value, where two products could share the same url_key. You can get url_path from the [catalog_product.info](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html) API call and you should be able to specify the optional [storeView](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html) argument for the API call to make the response specific to an individual store. You can use the [store.list](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/miscellaneous/store.list.html) API call to get a complete list of all stores in your Magento installation. It wouldn't be very efficient making multiple calls for each store, but it would give you the relevant information.