# Splitting wsdl.xml into several parts?

Tags: xml

I'm currently working on a large scale API for a project and I've wondered if it's possible to split the wsdl.xml needed into several parts. It's getting problematic to find my way around the file due to it's large size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wsdl files have to be named `wsdl.xml` (or wsi.xml if you have WS-I compliance on) and must me located in the `etc` folder of your module. So you cannot have files like `wsdl1.xml, wsdl2.xml` they will not get picked up unless you rewrite the `Mage_Api_Model_Wsdl_Config::init` method.  Side note: there is a wsdl2.xml loaded but only from the `Mage_Api` module.

But there is away. Not a pretty one, but it should work. You can split your module into multiple modules. Have your main module that handles all the logic and have separate modules that contain only the configuration file and the wsdl files. They will all be merged into one big xml. You can [read this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1331/146). It answers a different issue, but it should give you an idea of how wsdl files are merged when used and an idea of how you can split your files.

Comment: @Sourcedog. I'm not saying it's the only solution. I actually gave you 2 solutions :). One to override the config model and one to split the module. Those are the only ones I could thing of.

Comment: Dammit, no idea how I missed the first part (as in, read it but didn't register it as a workable solution).

Guess that's how I'll go then. Thanks again.