# how to add custom fields into a website/store?

Tags: module, multistore, magento-1, websites, stores

I need to add additional fields in the website, store and store view, including - store type, store pictures, contact number, store hours, store longitude, and latitude. The Store type will be a drop down list to allow people to choose the type etc. Could someone provide detailed steps for how to make this change?

Answer (score 3):

You can [see here an explanation](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2012/10/add-new-field-to-store-view.html) on how to add an extra field when editing a store view. You can do the same for websites and stores.
It involves adding a new column to the store view table and rewriting the admin block so you can add the field.
But I recommend you not to do that.
At least for websites and store views you can use the system->configuration section to add your fields. 
[Alan Storm explains it here nicely](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration) how it works and how you can add your configurations and how you can read the values from config.

Comment: Thanks Marius for your answer, could you advise how to add additional fields in system->configuration section? do I need to make code change as Alan Storm explained or it can be done by just simple config on the system->configuration admin GUI?

Comment: You need to create your own extension that contains a `system.xml` file where you define the fields for your configuration settings. Look in Alan's blog post for things related to `system.xml`. Adding fields in your system.xml will make them display in the system->configuration section

Comment: Thanks Marius for quick response, I also want the new fields to be returned in the store list and store info API call, how can I make it happen? http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/miscellaneous/store.list.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/miscellaneous/store.info.html

Comment: that's a different story. It's kind of a long answer.  Here is an example on how you can extend the api response http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1331/146

Comment: question for creating new extension to support the additional fields for website/store, do we need to make any db table change?